# Can't locate Class/CSV.pm in @INC

Tags: windows, perl, csv

I am trying to use Text::CSV in my Perl codes on Windows, but it gives me error "Can't locate Class/CSV.pm in @INC (You may need to install the class:CSV module"). (@INC contains C:\Perl64\site\lib C:\Perl64\lib.)

I found CSV.pm in 3 different location: C:\Perl64\lib\SQL\Dialects\CSV.pm, C:\Perl64\lib\DBD\CSV.pm and C:\Perl64\lib\Bundle\DBD\CSV.pm.

I then used lib command in the program itself to add the search path like the below, but still get the same error :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use lib 'C:\Perl64\lib\Bundle\DBD'; 
use Class::CSV; 
use Text::CSV;
```

How can I fix this error ?
Thank you.

Comment: From what I see `Class::CSV` is a different module that uses `Text::CSV_XS`.  Did you check that `Text::CSV` itself is installed?  (And then try with just `use Text::CSV;` line)

Comment: `Class::CSV` should be located in `...\Class\CSV.pm`.

Comment: @zdim: How can I check if Text::CSV is installed ?

Comment: @choroba: I found CSV.pm in these 3 different locations, but I don't see a Class folder: C:\Perl64\lib\SQL\Dialects\CSV.pm, C:\Perl64\lib\DBD\CSV.pm and C:\Perl64\lib\Bundle\DBD\CSV.pm.

Comment: Remove the first two `use ...` lines in your example above, leaving only `use Text::CSV;` -- then run the program.  If all is well it will do nothing, if the module is missing it will give you errors.

Comment: @zdim I removed all the lines from the top, and only have use Text::CSV; I am still getting the same error

Comment: @zdim The error now is "Can't locate Text/CSV.pm in.."

Comment: @faujong It's because you need to install the Text::CSV module. Neither SQL::Dialects::CSV nor DBD::CSV is Text::CSV.

Comment: @Matt Jacob Thank you. I installed TEXT:CSV module from https://code.activestate.com/ppm/Text-CSV, and now it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the `use lib` line from your program. It is incorrect, and will have no effect.
2. Remove `use Class::CSV` as well. This module isn't installed on your computer, and you shouldn't install it. It is a very old, weird wrapper around `Text::CSV` and serves very little purpose; just use `Text::CSV` directly.

Comment: I only have Text::CSV; at the top of my Perl script, and still getting the same error  "Can't locate Class/CSV.pm in.."

Comment: Are you sure you're editing the right file? The only way you'll get `Can't locate Class/CSV.pm` is from `use Class::CSV`.

Comment: I am so sorry.. the error now is "Can't locate Text/CSV.pm in.."

Comment: Then you need to install Text::CSV, like it says.

Comment: Thank you. I installed TEXT:CSV module from https://code.activestate.com/ppm/Text-CSV, and now it works. Thank you.